# R: How can create a new categorical variable based on multiple conditions

Tags: r, if-statement, filter, dplyr

Hi I am new to R so this might have a simple solution but I can't seem to work it out.

I am working with data from people who are in a relationship.

I have subset of my data with three variables familyID and var1female and var1male (with scores of 0 [never experienced behaviour] or 1 [has experienced behaviour) with over 9000 observations.

I would like to create a new categorical variable with 4 levels that shows if and who has engaged in the behavior that var1 depicts( 0= never experienced, 1= female only, 2=male only and 3= both female and male.

For example row one would be a 3 as both female and male have a score of 1.

This is what my data looks like (can't do it manually as I have over 9000 observations)

```
FAMID IPAsum_totalMd IPAsum_totalPd
  <dbl>          <dbl>          <dbl>
1 10405              1              1
2 10426              0              0
3 10429              1              0
4 10431              0              1
5 10432              0              0
6 10433              1              1
```

I have been going over the examples online but haven't been able to find anything similar.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `case_when` and list the conditions to check in it.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(result = case_when(IPAsum_totalMd == 0 & IPAsum_totalPd == 0 ~ 0, 
                            IPAsum_totalMd == 0 & IPAsum_totalPd == 1 ~ 1, 
                            IPAsum_totalMd == 1 & IPAsum_totalPd == 0 ~ 2, 
                            TRUE ~ 3))

#  FAMID IPAsum_totalMd IPAsum_totalPd result
#1 10405              1              1      3
#2 10426              0              0      0
#3 10429              1              0      2
#4 10431              0              1      1
#5 10432              0              0      0
#6 10433              1              1      3
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is what I needed.